# Fittings of three equations

Tags: fitting

Can you help me to do the fit for the following equations to obtain the values of $a$ and $b$.

```
{20.7 == a + b/(5^4), 28.62 == a + b/(6^4), 32.04 == a + b/(7^4)}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [`FindFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) to find the best least-squares fit.

```
data = {{5^4, 20.7}, {6^4, 28.62}, {7^4, 32.04}};
model = a + b/x;
fitVals = FindFit[data, model, {a, b}, x]
(* {a -> 36.0214, b -> -9577.97} *)
```

It turns out be a rather good fit.

```
Plot[model /. fitVals, {x, 5^4 - 10, 7^4 + 10}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[data]}]
```

> [image]

```
Norm[(model /. fitVals /. x -> (First /@ data)) - (Last /@ data) ]
(* 0.0138648 *)
```

Comment: @Fuad That is the right solution. Two others, including the accepted one do not represent a fit as was requested in the question.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Thank you very much Suba Thomas.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yarchik for you comments.

Answer (score 3):

I like the solution from @morbo but think that Subsets is better in this case than Permutations.  Permutations will give {1,3} and {3,1} (thinking of this as a set of three values and just looking at indices) and clearly, these yield identical solutions.  So something like this gives the three cases we care about:

```
eqns = {20.7 == a + b/(5^4), 28.62 == a + b/(6^4), 
   32.04 == a + b/(7^4)};
list = Subsets[eqns, {2}];
Table[Solve[list[[i]], {a, b}], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Good eye, yes subset is better!

Comment: This is not a fit. There are 3 equations and 2 variables. The fit means you try to find approximate parameters minimizing the total error. Here, there are just multiple partial solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You have an over defined system namely, 3 equations and 2 variables, as such, you can solve for two equations, but which values are the 'fit' you want, I don't know.

We will generate all combinations:

```
eqns = {20.7 == a + b/(5^4), 28.62 == a + b/(6^4), 32.04 == a + b/(7^4)};
list = Permutations[eqns, {2}];
```

Then generate the solutions for all possible combinations.

```
Table[Solve[list[[i]], {a, b}], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \{a\to 35.997,b\to -9560.66\} \\
 \{a\to 36.0307,b\to -9581.69\} \\
 \{a\to 35.997,b\to -9560.66\} \\
 \{a\to 36.0511,b\to -9630.77\} \\
 \{a\to 36.0307,b\to -9581.69\} \\
 \{a\to 36.0511,b\to -9630.77\} \\
\end{array}
\right) $

Though your question isn't quite clear what you're looking for, hope this is it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: A suggestion to the last command line **Union[Table[Solve[list[[i]], {a, b}], {i, 1, Length[list]}]]**

Comment: This is not a fit.

Comment: @yarchik They are analytical solutions. And seemingly not bad ones. considering there are only three data points and 3 equations it's perfectly fine. There are many methods for madness.

Comment: These are partial solutions. To find a fit means that one seeks for parameters that fulfill (at least approximately) all 3 equations. `LeastSquares` is the proper way in the given case.

Comment: And they fit within a tolerance. The question never imposed any restrictions. These are valid fits. Better than a band of .9 i even asked for more clarification and got none.